# Using Greedy approach, given an m × n boolean matrix B, find its largest square submatrix whose elements are all zeros

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Anybody know using greedy approach please help me out this problem.I have already done this by dynamic approach. But my main concern is by using Greedy method. And also we have to find max square sub-matrix of 0's.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/ 
Here is the example using dynamic approach and finding elements having 1's. 
NOTE:using greedy

Comment: You should mention why do you want to use greedy approach insead of dp. Dp approach provide solution in O(n*m) and need extra O(n*m) space. I can clearly see you can not optimize run time than O(n*m). Do you want to optimize space?

Comment: i am in learning process so i just want to know how it works in greedy approach.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy approach is where you make a locally optimal choice, believing that it will lead to the optimal solution. So basically we start by searching for a 0 in one of the four margins of the mXn matrix i.e. in the 1st row, last row, first column or last column. Once a 0 is found, we start by searching for the largest square possible.

Example-

0 0 1 1 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 0 0 0

1 1 1 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0

In the above example, the first element is 0, so check for the presence of 5X5 matrix, it fails as the third element is 1. There are a few cases now-

1] If you leave the first row from further evaluation, you can still aim for a matrix of size  4X4.

2] If you leave the third column and consider only the first two columns, aim for 2X2 matrix.

3] If you leave the third column and consider only the last three columns, aim for 3X3 matrix.

4] We wouldn't consider the option of eliminating both the row and the column, as it wouldn't be any better than the previous three options.

Considering greedy, we would choose the 1st case and repeat the process.